# How to create a path to xml element in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create a routing(path) to xml element and assign it to a variable so i can access it
fast in the future.
The element, which is a child of other elements, can change its position in the document
so i cant use methods like first child or indexing that rely on position.
The path to the element will always stay constant and there is no other path like it.
If we look at a short example so i want a path to level4 value(header4) so i can modify it.

```
    <level1>
    <level2>
        <level3>header3</level3>
            <level4>header4</level4>
        <level3>header31</level31>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3>nnn</level3>
        <level3>nnnnn</level31>
    </level2>
</level1>
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov lol whoops. Silly me. Been a long day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to use XPath in that case.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Path of the xml");
XmlNode titleNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//level1/level2/level3");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath for this.

```
XmlDocument doc; // assuming the xml is already in doc
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/level1/level2/level3/level4");
if(node != null) 
{
    node.InnerText = "New value";
}
```

If there could be more than one level4 then you could do this:

```
XmlDocument doc; // assuming the xml is already in doc
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/level1/level2/level3/level4");
if(nodes != null) 
{
    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.InnerText = "New value";
    }
}
```